Why Use json.parse() Instead of json.parseObject() in First Assertion in Spring Boot JSON Test?
I'm working through a code example from the official Spring Academy course, specifically a test that deserializes JSON into a CashCard object using JacksonTester.
Here's the relevant code snippet:
package example.cashcard;

import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.json.JsonTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.json.JacksonTester;

import java.io.IOException;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

@JsonTest
class CashCardJsonTest {

    @Autowired
    private JacksonTester<CashCard> json;

    @Test
    void cashCardDeserializationTest() throws IOException {
       String expected = """
               {
                   "id":99,
                   "amount":123.45
               }
               """;
       assertThat(json.parse(expected))
               .isEqualTo(new CashCard(1000L, 67.89));
       assertThat(json.parseObject(expected).id()).isEqualTo(1000);
       assertThat(json.parseObject(expected).amount()).isEqualTo(67.89);
    }
}

In the first assertion, json.parse(expected) returns an ObjectContent<CashCard>, which works fine with the assertThat from AssertJ. However, json.parseObject(expected) directly returns a CashCard object, which seems like it could also be used for the first assertion.
Since the test works either way, can anyone clarify the difference between json.parse() and json.parseObject(), and why we would use parse() in the first assertion rather than parseObject()? Or more specifically, why would we use ObjectContent<CashCard> instead of the CashCard itself, when they seem to behave similarly?

json.parse(expected).getObject() seems equivalent to json.parseObject(expected).
I think you can use either one, as they essentially do the same thing.
In fact, json.parseObject(expected) internally calls json.parse(expected)
